# Angular 7 Manually set background color to tile

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

Here is my code :

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        1
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        2
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        3
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        4
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="1">
        5
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

I want to manually apply a background color to these tiles. 
I know that I can use this method :     `_setStyle(property: string, value: any): void;`

But I have no idea how in my case, since I didn't initialize any MatGridTile object in my component. I don't want to use a dynamically filled grid.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adjmya?file=app/grid-list-dynamic-example.html

Comment: Try using `::ng-deep` . can u provide a demo code so that we can provide u some solution

Comment: @ShashankVivek its too complex to provide a demo with angular (or I never found an easy way to do so) sorry....

Comment: Can u modify https://stackblitz.com/angular/oalnrrygvga?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html and show us ?

Comment: Oh man I forgot about that (and Im using it lol), sure I can

Comment: How do I save the damn thing ?? @ShashankVivek

Comment: Click on "fork" first and then save :D

Comment: Yes right thanks, I ve added it to my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `"'red'"` in `[style.background]`

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2" [style.background]="'red'">
        1
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        2
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        3
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        4
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="1">
        5
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[Demo code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adjmya-hun7f1?file=app/grid-list-dynamic-example.html)

### Update:

The reason it required `'` single quotes is because as per the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oalnrrygvga?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.html), we can see that it expects

```
[style.background]="tile.color"
```

which shows that it takes `angular` variable and interpolate it. By providing `'` , you tell **material component** that its a string and not some angular variable defined in the `component`. Otherwise, with `style.backgroundColor="red"` , it looks for a variable named `red` in the component.

Comment: Wow this is actually working !! I hate the angular doc sometimes... how did you find out ? thank you anyway :)

Comment: well, I still can't find that anywhere in the material doc (neither in the angular website nor in the doc within my IDE, like in the grid-tile.d.ts file), could you give me a source of that ? for my information :D

Comment: @DevMoutarde added explanation in my provided answer

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `style.backgroundColor`:

```
<mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="2" [style.backgroundColor]="'red'">
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/koonqmpnbqen?file=app%2Fgrid-list-dynamic-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you but its not working, I already tried that. Also my IDE is telling me I cannot use that property here anyway so I guess its right...

Comment: in app component css file : mat-grid-tile {
  background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: thanks but how can I select a specific tile to color ? right now every tile is getting yellow colored lol

Comment: @DevMoutarde apparently it really needs to be bound using brackets. Check my update. Also check the stackblitz I attached for a working example

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3" [rowspan]="1" style="background-color: lightblue">
```